# Convert USPS Manager class C# code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, usps

I have some working USPS Manager C# code but need to execute it from Google Apps Script in JavaScript.

How would I convert the below to JavaScript format?

```
USPSManager m = new USPSManager("YOUR_USER_ID", true);
Address a = new Address();
a.Address2 = "6406 Ivy Lane";
a.City = "Greenbelt";
a.State = "MD";
Address addressWithZip = m.GetZipcode(a);
string zip = addressWithZip.Zip;
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Using the code outlined below in GAS I receive the below error:
[image]

Comment: Convert?  You don't  -- You see `new USPSManager` and `new Address()` are C# instantiations -- Unless you rewrite the entire class library.  You MAY be able to *call* this functionality from JS .. But that's beyond the scope of this post ..

Answer (score 0):

Here it is "translated" into JavaScript. Thing is, if USPS doesn't have a `USPSManager` class written in JavaScript, then this isn't going to work - or you'll have to write one yourself.

```
const m = new USPSManager("YOUR_USER_ID", true);
const a = new Address();
a.Address2 = "6406 Ivy Lane";
a.City = "Greenbelt";
a.State = "MD";
const addressWithZip = m.GetZipcode(a);
const zip = addressWithZip.Zip;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing code in JavaScript, using a C# library will not work. You need to use a JavaScript library.

A quick search on NPM found this [`usps-webtools` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usps-webtools).

Here is how you would use it in code:

```js
// Old CommonJS Modules syntax:
const USPS = require('usps-webtools');
// or, if your platform supports the newer ECMAScript Module syntax:
import USPS from 'usps-webtools';

const usps = new USPS({
    server: 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll',
    userId: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
});

const address = {
  street2: '6406 Ivy Lane',
  city: 'Greenbelt',
  state: 'MD'
};

usps.zipCodeLookup(address, (error, address) => {
    if (error) {
        // handle error here
        return;
    }
    const zip = address.zip;
    // use that result here
});
```

Comment: I added this:  npm install usps-webtools
  Looks like i need to run this command now inside the GAS editor but require is not supported.  Do you know the next step?      
    const USPS = require('usps-webtools');

Comment: @Raptor I added a code example

Comment: Thank you.  I dont seem to be able to use that code in the GAS editor.  Is there another way that you know of?  I added a screen shot above.